# Contentaccesible and Chrome.Manifest

Tags: firefox-addon, manifest

This is my chrome.manifest file:

```
content ghforkable ./
content_scripts ghforkable content_scripts/ contentaccessible=yes
```

It doesn't seem to work though, I keep getting this security error:

> Security Error: Content at https://github.com/ may not load or link to
>   chrome://ghforkable/content/content_scripts/inject.js.

Answer (score 0):

Solution thanks to litho and pat from mozillazine. There can be more than one content folder, with one being marked as contentaccessible:

```
content ghforkable ./
content ghforkable-scripts content_scripts/ contentaccessible=yes
```

The script `chrome://ghforkable-scripts/content/inject.js` can then be injected into webpages.