# Content Security Policy on Mozilla extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla, content-security-policy

I have an extension in both Mozilla and Chrome, in my extension I make a call to a remote JS file.

To avoid the CSP in Chrome, I add the rule to manifest.json and my file goin over HTTPS so everything is perfect.

But in Mozilla, I could not find out how to load the JS. Even over https dont work.
The only thing I found on this was another question here on Stackoverflow: [How to add Content Security Policy to Firefox extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19264831/how-to-add-content-security-policy-to-firefox-extension), but are not sure where to insert that code, my extension its very simple.

I just need that, how i can handle CSP on a Firefox addon?

Thanks and sorry for my English!

Comment: You have to add contentaccessible=yes

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751559/contentaccesible-and-chrome-manifest

Comment: Thanks! But I can insert local JS from the extension, but I need to do it with a remote JS, from a certain URL. In chrome as I say there are the option "content_security_policy" in the manifest, and then I can insert external JS, but in Mozil la I dont have idea how to do that. The contentaccessible seems only working for local files of the extension...

Comment: I dont understand, post up your code and point where the problem is and ill be able to tell what you're trying to do :)

Comment: For example in my JS i have: `(function(d, t) {var g = d.createElement(t),s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];g.async = true;g.src = '//googlecode.com/my.js';s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);})(document, 'script');` That code its executed normally, but it trhows a CSP error with the file googlecode.com/my.js (its a example URL). I mean, how I can inject a remote file... BTW @Noitidart i send you a email on your website, hopre you read it. Thanks!

Comment: Hey man my email form on website is broken haha email me at noitidart@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notidart help me a lot with this problem. With the help of the link I gave, Notidart work on this extension just for testing:

https://github.com/Noitidart/_ff-addon-template-BootstrapWatchHostEventListenerInjectJQUERY/tree/patch-1

That extension inject a JS file and an Image just for example, and Have Implemented the code that Jai Prakash put on [How to add Content Security Policy to Firefox extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19264831/how-to-add-content-security-policy-to-firefox-extension) and its working well. It injects the file on all sites with a CSP defined.

Thank you very much to both, there is no easy way or documentation for avoid the CSP in Firefox extensions, but this solution works very well.